# What's the difference between the Leam Empire and the Goi

Tags: magi

What's the difference between the Leam Empire and the Goi? Who are the people who live in 5th District or 5th level?

What's the difference between The Kou Empire and the Organization, Are they the same?

Morgiana went to see her family "Fanalis" in Dark Continent but there was a Magician told her that he can send her there "Another Place" but she can't get back, On the other hand How The Fanalis Corps where helping Leam Empire during the war with Magunoshutatto?

Comment: you seem to be asking multiple distinct questions at once which should really be asked as [separate questions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). please [edit](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/43534/edit) this question to have one question and ask the rest separately

Comment: i will suggest you to edit your question...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Humans who are not magicians and have little magoi are basically "goi". It is a derogatory term used by Matal Mogamett. Magnostadt's 5th district consists of the non-magicians, also known as "goi". 
The kou empire is an empire/country. It's just that the organisation is sort of affliated with kou empire.(I won't explain much if not it may be spoilers) hence they are different

[Morgiana went to see her family "Fanalis" in Dark Continent but there was a Magician told her that he can send her there "Another Place" but she can't get back, On the other hand How The Fanalis Corps where helping Leam Empire during the war with Magunoshutatto?]--------------------

first of all, it's a MAGI who told morgiana that.

SPOILER ALERT>> 
.
.
.
I think the leader or someone from fanalis corps (maybe Muu?) insisted on going to "that place" and he started to realise that he belonged there, and started reverting to his original form as a fanalis. Once he completes it, he probably can't change back (I forgot why though) 
but the magi who talked to morgiana found him, and said that he was "too young" and sent him back, away from "that place"

Do read the manga for more details.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se] (and Stack Exchange in general). We appreciate that you tried to answer this post. However, as of current writing, multiple unrelated questions in a single post is not encouraged and thus shouldn't be answered until the question is edited accordingly to follow the rule.